# How to dynamically update a storageTank in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

I have a tank with storageTank space markup. I am setting the initial amount externally, via `tank.set_initialAmount(xxxx, CUBIC_METER);`

How can we update storageTank to show this initial amount?

Once the simulation is started and as soon as the tank volume is updated, the storageTank will "jump" the tank volume.

[image]

[image]

[image]

and here is at run-time. 500 is in the tank but the markup is not up to date

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to place that code in main startup sectioin:

[image: tank startup]

Comment: This is what I had in my code. I am not sure what I am missing but this does not work. It does update the initial amount properly in the tank but it does not update the storageTank space markup

Comment: then you are not assigning the storage tank to the tank... be sure that you are doing that... this should DEFINITELY work

Comment: I have updated my original posting with screen capture

Comment: I see. that's because your tank needs to be connected to something... connected to a source in the input and a sink in the output, define a maximum output rate.. and it will work